# Problem Book in Elementary Maths

Tags: soft-question, contest-math, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I would like a book recommendation.

Could you kindly point out some Olympiad style problem compilations, with relatively easier problem, but escalating with time. Topics must include Algebra, Geometry, Combinatorics and Elementary Number Theory.

As of now, I posses The USSR Problem Book, which is quite good for Algebra and Elementary Number Theory but lacks Geometry and Combinatorics (counting problems, basically). I have Sharygin's Problems in Plane Geometry, which suffices. But still no problem books in Combinatorics.

If you recommend a book with all of the above that would contribute to my problem solving skills, I would be grateful. And the book should have TONS of problems, literally.

Thanks, y'all!!!

Comment: Have a look at AoPS!

Comment: The book or the site, sir?

Comment: On this site you will find some books!

Comment: Thanks, sir! Will look into it!

Comment: Have a look at the book store!

Comment: How about Problem-Solving Strategies, by Arthur Engel?

Comment: @Mindlack PSS is good, but it's Combinatorics seems incomprehensible.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit out of touch the Olympiads, in my opinions. The rest is really good, though.

Comment: What about The IMO Compendium? Not only do they have the actual problems from 1959-2009, they also have longlisted and shortlisted problems for some years as well. All mathematical concepts are before all the problems. They also have solutions to some problems as well.